# How I got a System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' when executing a SqlCommand in C#?

Tags: c#

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String source = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Szabolcs\Documents\Adatbázis Kezelés3.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);
    con.Open();

    // Exception here
    String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Username = "
                          + int.Parse(label1.Text);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if ( dr.Read() )
    {
        label3.Text = dr["Wins"].ToString();
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

[Database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTRDk.png)
How can i fix this error?

Comment: If i delete this System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '='.' `String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Username = " + label1.Text;`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. Your question has a low quality. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), images or sketches of screens, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: At what line did you got exception? You should use sql parameters for security reason instead of string concatenation for the sql request.

Comment: At line 32 was exeption

Comment: What is line 32 ? Can you indicate that in the question, please ?

Comment: Line 32: `String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Username = '" + label1.Text + "'";`

Comment: @.Szabolcs This book may help you to learn ADO.NET step-by-step, I found it great and none is comparable: [Beginning C# 2005 Databases](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Beginning+C%23+2005+Databases-p-9780470044063)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Username` is a string column, you need to add  Apostrophe `'` to the string text value

try:

```
String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Username = '" +label1.Text+"'";
```

it's better to use SqlParamaters for more security

```
String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Username = @UserName";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);
    
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = label1.Text;
```

Comment: Its working but not write out the data what i need

Comment: Does not enter: `if (dr.Read())` How can i fix this?

Comment: The edited version is has error

Comment: @Szabolcs what the error you get?

Comment: Error: Cannot use local variable 'cmd' before it is declare

Comment: you need to move the line SqlCommand cmd and set it before the cmd.parametes .... i update the answer

Comment: Can you show me the ful of the code because its doesent works

Comment: @Szabolcs what you get ? it should work ! send your query

Comment: So the program need to do: I have one account the account have "Wins". If i login to one account the program need show to count of "Wins" "Wins" = column

Comment: if the query will return one row only, you don't need the SqlDataReader  line and if ( dr.Read() ) line , just change the query to "select Wins from ......" and to get the value you can write: label3.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); please see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1